# How to get reference to another object on other column on same row in a table in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, object, input, this

I want to set **disabled=false** for the **input box on 3rd column** when a user **'check' the checkbox** on the **2nd column** **on Same row**
And **again disable if user 'uncheck' the checkbox**.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Check the checkbox to display which type of form element it is.</p>

<table border='1' cellpadding='5'>
<tr>
<td>Item1</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
<td><input type='number' disabled></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Item2</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
<td><input type='number' disabled></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Item3</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
<td><input type='number' disabled></td>
<tr>
</table>


<script>
//  function myFunction(item) {
//      var x = document.getElementById(item).....how to get a reference to parent;
//      x.disabled=false;  
//  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

*I tried with `this`  reference but that have not gave me any solution*.

**So how can i get the reference to the input box from the checkbox?**
I browsed internet but have not get any solution .

Comment: When calling myFunction the event (onclick) is passed which has a property "target".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give the inputs an `id` attribute for later addressing this element.

```js
function myFunction(item) {
  var x = document.getElementById(item);
  x.disabled = !x.disabled;
}
```

```html
<p>Check the checkbox to display which type of form element it is.</p>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td>Item1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction('itemInput1')"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="itemInput1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction('itemInput2')"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="itemInput2" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item3</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction('itemInput3')"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="itemInput3" disabled></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

With [`Element.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), as [@August](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49797781/1447675) mentioned and [`Document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```js
function myFunction(element) {
  var x = element.closest('tr').querySelector('input[type="number"]');
  x.disabled = !x.disabled;
}
```

```html
<p>Check the checkbox to display which type of form element it is.</p>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td>Item1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td><input type="number" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td><input type="number" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item3</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td><input type="number" disabled></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Really this is so simple to implement , I was thinking so complex so i just missed this easy solution.  But Still this may be not helpful  if i have thousand of rows. I have to set id for each of the item.  Is there any other  dynamic solution?

Comment: thank this is the perfect answer what i searching. Thnx agin very much

Answer (score 1):

Don't go back to DOM with document.getElementById to get your element, there is no point of doing that.

Try to use the event reference, when calling myFunction the event (onclick) is passed which has property "target".
To understand better do console.log(item); inside the function.

From there, inside your function you could do item.target.closest('tr') to identify the parent of the cell.

```
<script>
  function myFunction(item) {
      console.log(item);
      var x = item.target.closest('tr');
      x.disabled=false;  
  }
</script>
```

Documentation for [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method

Comment: Would you please give a long example please

Comment: It giving result: TypeError: item.target is undefined